# How can we use an existing NewRelic account with our CloudBees apps?

Tags: cloudbees, newrelic

If we have an existing NewRelic account, how can we direct our CloudBees apps to use that account rather than the on-the-fly account that's created by activating New Relic plugin on our CloudBees app configuration screen? This would enable us to utilize license pricing we've already paid for and allow us a central New Relic console screen for all our apps, whether they're running on CloudBees or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a New Relic configuration file to my CloudBees app and inside that config file I specify the license key for my New Relic account and now all my CloudBees and non-CloudBees apps are available under my New Relic console. If you follow [these instructions](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/NewRelic) to update and deploy the newrelic.yml file and specify your own license key, you should immediately start seeing your app reporting on your existing New Relic console.